# Threejs crashing when rendering a huge mesh with different materials

Tags: javascript, three.js, crash

So I have a mehs which has around 59k cubes in it. I wanted to assign a different color to each cube, so I did that using a MeshFaceMaterial.

But when I went to the webpage, it instantly crashed in Chrome. So I tried Firefox instead, since it has better dev tools, and it rendered part of the cubes, then froze and crashed horribly.

Is a MeshFaceMaterial not made to handle around 59k materials? or is it just rendering so many materials that is the issue?

Comment: Are you using a different material for each cube? If you want to have different colors, you can try using vertex colors.

Comment: changing `materials` of making `state changes` in general is very Expensive.

Comment: @vorsk Are vertex colors facer then using a face material on a large mesh?

Comment: @gaitat I'm not changing any materials, I'm assigning them all before the scene loads

Comment: @KeithM Vertex colors use more memory, but less draw calls. If you want to give each cube a different color, vertex colors are perfect for that.

Comment: @vorsk OK,  I'll try them out when I'm on my computer next

Comment: it doesn't matter if you assign the materials at init time or you change them. at rendering time you want WebGL to make 59K `state changes` (i.e. material changes) to render your scene. That is waaaaaaaay too many `changes` (by a factor of 1000). Have you tried loading your model with just one material to see if it loads?

Comment: @gaitat yes,  it loads at 60 fps with a single basic material

Comment: so now you know `its the materials fault`. do you have 59K discrete materials? any way of using less? a cube with color (255, 255, 255) and one with color (255, 255, 250) is probably not going to be distinguishable.

Comment: The cubes are going to be coloured with Th e set of data I have that generated them.  It will probably be at lease a hundred different colours